# How to convert a string of hours and minutes to minutes in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe df:

```
Time
2 hours 3 mins
5 hours 10 mins
1 hour 40 mins
```

I want to create a new column in df 'Minutes' that converts this column over to minutes

```
Minutes
123
310
100
```

Is there a python function to do this?

Answer (score 11):

You need to convert it via `to_datetime`

```
s=pd.to_datetime(df.Time.replace({'hours':'hour'},regex=True),format='%H hour %M mins')
s.dt.hour*60+s.dt.minute
Out[406]: 
0    123
1    310
2    100
Name: Time, dtype: int64
```

Or we using `str.findall` with `numpy` `dot`

```
np.dot(np.array(df.Time.str.findall('\d+').tolist()).astype(int),[60,1])
Out[420]: array([123, 310, 100])
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Fun with `pd.eval`

```
df['Minutes'] = pd.eval(
    df['Time'].replace(['hours?', 'mins'], ['*60+', ''], regex=True))
df
              Time Minutes
0   2 hours 3 mins     123
1  5 hours 10 mins     310
2   1 hour 40 mins     100
```

The idea is to have `replace` convert this into a mathematical expression, then have pandas evaluate it:

```
expr = df['Time'].replace(['hours?', 'mins'], ['* 60 +', ''], regex=True)
expr

0    2 * 60 +  3 
1    5 * 60 + 10 
2    1 * 60 + 40 
Name: Time, dtype: object

pd.eval(expr)
# array([123, 310, 100], dtype=object)
```

---

#### `str.extract` and multiplication

```
((df['Time'].str.extract(r'(\d+) hour.*?(\d+) min').astype(int) * [60, 1])
            .sum(axis=1))

0    123
1    310
2    100
dtype: int64
```

Write a simple regex to extract the digits, then convert to minutes using simple arithmetic. You can shorten the pattern to

```
(df['Time'].str.extract(r'(\d+)\D*(\d+)').astype(int) * [60, 1]).sum(axis=1)

0    123
1    310
2    100
dtype: int64
```

As per @Quang Hoang's suggestion.

Comment: Not when you're always late for the party. 
:-). btw, my pattern is `'(\d+)\D*(\d+)'`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks that is shorter (I've updated if you don't mind) but my initial objective was to be explicit with my matching.

Comment: What to do in case there is no "hours" in some cases?

Answer (score 2):

"Is there a python function to do this?"
not until you write one ...

```
def to_minutes(time_string):
    hours, _, minutes, _ = time_string.split(' ')
    return int(hours) * 60 + int(minutes)
```

Result should look something like:

```
>>> to_minutes('2 hours 3 mins')
123
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can convert to `timedelta` and cast to `timedelta64[m]`:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.Time.str.replace('mins', 'm'), unit='m').astype('timedelta64[m]')

Out[786]:
0    123.0
1    310.0
2    100.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fancy lambda functions you can also use:

```
df.Time.apply(lambda x: sum(np.array([ int(i) for i in re.match(r'(\d+) hour[s]? (\d+) min[s]?', x).groups()]) * [60, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the Time column is always in the same format (same amount of spaces) you can use -

```
def Mins(row):
    return int(row['Time'].split(' ')[0])*60 + int(row['Time'].split(' ')[2])

df.apply(Mins,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in function, but you can build one, and then use it in pandas with .apply().

It might not be the shortest answer, but it will let you understand how to use basic Python functions with Pandas. I think it's very helpful!

The function I built:

```
import re

def calculate_number_of_minutes(hours_string):
    regex = '\d+( )\w+'
    // I build a regex which can find a sequence of digits and a single word


    result = re.finditer(regex, text, re.DOTALL)
    // I find such patterns in the given string

    minutes = 0
    for element in result:
        fragment = element.group()

        if 'hour' in fragment:
            minutes += int(re.search('\d+', fragment).group()) * 60
            // if there are 'hours', the associated number is multiplied by 60
            // and added to the count
        else:
            minutes += int(re.search('\d+', fragment).group())

    return minutes


text = '5 hours 10 mins'
print(calculate_number_of_minutes(text))
```

What it does is search your string for numbers, then count the minute counts.

In order to apply it to your column, try this:

```
data.loc[;, 'Time'] = data['Time'].apply(lambda x: calculate_number_of_minutes(x))
```

Hope it's useful ;)